# making a rotated text responsive for screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, rotation

I am making a website that has a text rotated -90. because it is at the edge of the screen, it disappears. I am putting padding of 5vw to keep inside the screen, but it still disappears when changing the screen size. I have the text inside a grid. How do I keep it inside the screen and make it responsive?

[image: rotated aboutus]

```css
.aboutus {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10vw 88vw;
}

h1.titleaboutus {
  text-align: center;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  color: #4778a6;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutus">
  <h1 class="titleaboutus">About us</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: since your h1 is rotated, the padding now is on the left side.. check by inspecting your element

Comment: @Sfili_81 I didn't know about that. Chrome shows a `margin-top` for example on the left side, but applies it correctly on the top, but `padding-top` behaves strangely by moving it right and down. What is happening there?

Answer (score 2):

One problem with using transforms is that the dimensions - as far as the whole layout is concerned - do not change. So the height of that grid row has not expanded to accommodate the rotated element.

Instead of relying on rotation, you can use writing-mode to turn the text. This will give the h1 the correct height. To get the text facing the other way we then need to rotate the element 180degrees and move it back into the grid. (or you could alter the tranfrom origin).

```css
.aboutus {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10vw 88vw;
}

h1.titleaboutus {
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  color: #4778a6;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutus">
  <h1 class="titleaboutus">About us</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `font-size` and/or `padding` more responsive by using `clamp`

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()

You could also simply use a media query.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: It's not what OP is asking

Comment: Hmm I'll leave it up in case it is helpful anyways.

Comment: it's not helpful